# Using KeyCommands in UITextView - see my shortcuts *and* system shortcuts

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, xamarin.ios

I have a UITextView subclass, and I set up some shortcuts using KeyCommands (which just returns an array of UIKeyCommands):

```
public override UIKeyCommand[] KeyCommands {
    get
    {
        var sel = new ObjCRuntime.Selector("HandleKeyCommand:");
        return new UIKeyCommand[] {
            ....
            UIKeyCommand.Create((NSString)",", UIKeyModifierFlags.Command,
                                    sel, (NSString)"Toggle Bullets"),
            UIKeyCommand.Create((NSString)"/", UIKeyModifierFlags.Command,
                                    sel, (NSString)"Toggle Numbers"),
            UIKeyCommand.Create((NSString)"1", UIKeyModifierFlags.Command,
                                    sel, (NSString)"Heading 1"),
            ....
        }
    }
}
```

The shortcuts work fine. The only problem is the *display* of the shortcuts when I hold down the cmd key. I see *both* my short cuts, and the system shortcuts. See below:

[image: Display of both sets of shortcuts]

Does anyone know why this is happening, and how I can disable the display of the system shortcuts? Many thanks.

Comment: Could you tell me are you using a simulator or a real device? And how did you show this shortcuts view? I run a simulator on my mac and hold down the command key on the keyboard, however there is no response to me.

Comment: This is on a real device (iPad). Using an external keyboard, you hold down the cmd key in any app to see the shortcuts.

Comment: Interestingly... I've just noticed that other apps, including Calendar and Mail suffer from the same problem - that is their shortcuts are shown overlaid by the OS shortcuts. So this might just be an OS bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is (IMHO) an iOS bug. Only the current UI component's shortcuts should be shown, not the OS's. This problem happens with Mail, Calendar and other apple apps.

I've filed a bug with apple.

Here is it happening while editing a new email:

[image]